# How to group first by year than by month with EF?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I want to first group posts by year, then by month for an archive widget Such that I get something like:

```
2012
  January
  Febuary
  March
  Etc

2013
  January
  Febuary
  March
  Etc
```

This is what i have so far:

```
  Public Function SelectYearandMonth() As IEnumerable(Of ArchiveMonthYearViewModel)
        Dim posts
        posts = _postRepository.SelectAll.Where(Function(p)
        p.PostIsPublished).GroupBy(Function(p) New ArchiveMonthYearViewModel()
        With {.Year = p.PostDateCreated.Year, .Month = 
        .PostDateCreated.Month}).Select(Function(a) a.Key).ToList
  End Sub
```

Do I need two selects? Like first the year and then an inner select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
Public Function SelectYearandMonth() As IEnumerable(Of ArchiveMonthYearViewModel)
    Dim data = db.be_Posts.Where(Function(p) p.IsPublished = True).GroupBy(Function(a) _
    New With {.Month = a.DateCreated.Value.Month, .Year = a.DateCreated.Value.Year}).Select(Function(x) _
    New ArchiveMonthYearViewModel With {.Month = x.Key.Month, .Year = x.Key.Year, 
   .Total = x.Count}).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Year).ThenByDescending(Function(x)
    (x.Month)).ToList
    Return data
        End Function
```